# Could not load file or assembly 'msshrtmi' - when publishing Windows Azure Websites

Tags: azure, azure-web-roles

I'm having an issue as below:

```
 Could not load file or assembly 'msshrtmi, Version=2.3.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'msshrtmi, Version=2.3.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Source Error:

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Assembly Load Trace: The following information can be helpful to determine why the assembly 'msshrtmi, Version=2.3.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' could not be loaded.


WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF.
To enable assembly bind failure logging, set the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1.
Note: There is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure logging.
To turn this feature off, remove the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].
```

The issue happens **only when publishing to Windows Azure Websites (WAWS)**.  I want to detect whether I am running in Windows Azure mode or not.  Is this possible in WAWS?  This error is happening only when I call `Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime.RoleEnvironment.IsAvailable`.

I'd assume that the WAWS environment would have the Azure SDK installed, right? Or is this only available for Cloud services?

I've looked at some solutions telling you to manually include it in x64 or x86 version, but I would like not to be limited that way, or similar workarounds.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Could not load file or assembly 'msshrtmi' or one of its dependencies (Azure Table Storage Access)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8273321/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-msshrtmi-or-one-of-its-dependencies-azure-tab)

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this same error when publishing a Web App. After trying every other solution on the web, the following finally worked for me:

In the Azure Portal, select your Web App. Select 'Settings > Application settings'. Change the Platform value from 32-bit to 64-bit. Re-publish.