# Could not load file or assembly 'msshrtmi, Version=2.7.0.0 - what SDK installs it?

Tags: asp.net, .net, azure, azure-web-app-service

I'm trying to run an webapp that is using some Azure SDK (and storage) apis but when I try to run it, I always get this runtime error.

I have the project on a Windows 7 box with Visual Studio installed and a bunch of SDKs and it works but on this new Win10 machine I'm starting it doesn't work.

msshrtmi.dll is present on the new machine on `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\.NET SDK\v2.9\bin\runtimes\base\x86` (and x64 and in runtimes\net45\base) but on the old machine it is also on 
`c:\windows\Microsoft.net\assembly\GAC_XX\msshrtmi` and I can see on IIS that is from it's loaded.

If I manually copy `msshrtmi.dll` to my bin folder the project works just fine. I also know this file is required form `Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime`.

On this new machine I'm trying to avoid installing Visual Studio and using only Jetbrains Rider to build and run the project. It can build the project fine but now it doesn't run because of this.

Does the file really need to be on my windows\microsoft.NET folder? What installer puts it there? Or should I just include `msshrtmi.dll` as a dependency on my project?

Any other solutions for this problem?

I tried a lot of the solutions on other answers I encountered for this similar problem with no luck.

Edit: tried on ISS express 8 and 10

Answer (score 1):

There are several possible ways to solve this issue:

1.Copy the `msshrtmi.dll` manually to your project. For example in the `\bin` folder next to the `WindowsAzure.Storage.dll`.

2.Install the Windows Azure SDK on your server.

3.Change some configurations from `app.config`.

```
 <startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
  </startup>

  <runtime>
    <NetFx40_LegacySecurityPolicy enabled="false" />
  </runtime>
```

For more details, you could refer to this [article](http://vunvulearadu.blogspot.com/2012/11/how-to-fix-could-not-load-file-or.html) and this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8273321/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-msshrtmi-or-one-of-its-dependencies-azure-tab).

Comment: what do you mean by "2.Install the Windows Azure SDK on your server." ? I'm running all of this on localhost and already have azure sdk installed.

Comment: option 3 doesn't work. option 1 obviously work but I don't want to do it like this because otherwise I'll mess things up for the other members of the project